# require('os').cpus().length returns 24 .... can't understand how?

Tags: node.js, concurrent-programming

I have a windows desktop with this configuration: Intel Xeon(R) CPU  E5645 @2.40GHz  (2 processors)
with 24 GB RAM  and 64-bit OS

When I run following code.

```
var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
```

It returns cpuCount as 24

Can someone please explain what exactly does this mean? And how does it determine that I have 24 CPUs with just 2 processors.

Comment: The desktop has Windows 7 SP1 on it.

Comment: You should look at what the actual output says.  At a guess, each of your 2 processors have 6 cores, and each core can execute 2 simultaneous threads (this is some kind of smoke-and-mirrors Intel marketing stuff, mostly).  Each independent thread slot (2 per core) is likely exposed as a "CPU" through that interface, which would mean you have 24 such entries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...   I didn't understand what you meant by "You should look at what the actual output says"

Comment: I mean "print the output of `require('os').cpus()` and inspect it".

Answer (score 5):

http://ark.intel.com/products/48768/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5645-12M-Cache-2_40-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI?q=Xeon%20e5645

**Advanced Technologies** section. It says that your CPU supports [Hyper-Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)

From the Wikipedia:

> For each processor core that is physically present, the operating system addresses two virtual or logical cores ...

So, you have two processors with 6 physical cores each (but 12 logical or virtual):

(2 x 6) x 2 = 24

Also check out node.js [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus):

> os.cpus()
>
> Returns an array of objects containing information about each CPU/core installed: model, speed (in MHz), and times (an object containing the number of milliseconds the CPU/core spent in: user, nice, sys, idle, and irq).

That's why array returned by `require('os').cpus()` contains 24 elements.

Comment: Nice answer, although the documentation is not pretty clear. Assuming this case, it would better say that `os.cpus()` returns an array of objects containing information about each *virtual or logical* CPU/core.